# Rendering points with Leaflet from a `json.gz` file

Tags: javascript, python, json, leaflet

I am using the `SimpleHTTPServer` for Python to display a basic Leaflet map.

I wish to create a series of points on the map, using a `json.gz` file as input.

The contents of this file (`input.json.gz`) look like this:

```
[[25.0153,55.45758],[25.01767,55.45569],[25.02065,55.45327],[25.02655,55.44846]]
```

My hardcoded code looks like this:

```
var pointA = new L.LatLng(25.146619, 55.225746);
var pointB = new L.LatLng(25.198696, 55.269794);
```

How do I read the `json.gz` file in `javascript` and iterate across it creating `points`? Ultimately I will collect these points into different pointLists and from this render a polyline. Full code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<title>Leaflet Web Map</title>

<!-- reference to Leaflet CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css" />

<!-- reference to Leaflet JavaScript -->
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>

<!-- set width and height styles for map -->
<style>

html, body, #map {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
}

/* css to customize Leaflet default styles  */
.custom .leaflet-popup-tip,
.custom .leaflet-popup-content-wrapper {
    background: #e93434;
    color: #ffffff;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>

    <!-- place holder for map -->
    <div id="map"></div>

<script>

    //  create map object, tell it to live in 'map' div and give initial latitude, longitude, zoom values 
    var map = L.map('map', {scrollWheelZoom:false}).setView([25.198696, 55.269794], 15);

    //  add base map tiles from OpenStreetMap and attribution info to 'map' div
    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);
var pointA = new L.LatLng(25.146619, 55.225746);
    var pointB = new L.LatLng(25.198696, 55.269794);
    var pointList = [pointA,pointB];

    L.polyline(pointList,{icon: test_icon,color:'red','weight':10}).bindPopup(customPopup,customOptions).addTo(map);


</script>

</body>

</html>
```

**EDIT**

I have now reformatted my data into `geojson` format. Here is an exert:

```
{
 "type": "FeatureCollection", 
 "features": [
  {
   "geometry": {
    "type": "LineString", 
    "coordinates": [
     [
      25.1167, 
      55.19259
     ], 
     [
      25.11285, 
      55.18714
     ], 
     [
      25.11141, 
      55.1851
     ], 
     [
      25.11077, 
      55.18422
     ], 
     [
      25.11001, 
      55.18311
     ], 
     [
      25.10855, 
      55.18105
     ], 
     [
      25.10722, 
      55.17914
     ], 
     [
      25.10644, 
      55.17805
     ], 
     [
      25.10572, 
      55.17712
     ]
    ]
   }, 
   "type": "Feature", 
   "properties": {
    "url": "blah", 
    "name": "blue"
   }
  },
```

I then try and load it using `AJAX`.

```
var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("polylines.geojson");       

geojsonLayer.addTo(map);
```

I've also added `<script src="./polylines.geojson" type="text/javascript"></script>` to the top of the `html` file.

However, this returns file not found. I've the file located in the same directory as `index.html`

```
code 404, message File not found
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Mar/2017 14:52:40] "GET polylines.geojson HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Comment: use https://jsfiddle.net/ for providing your code sample!

Comment: I created one but it is not working. fix it! https://jsfiddle.net/e7y49mvo/

Comment: Oops, broken link - https://gist.github.com/gac55/3cca33aff70c8ca47ab2c9a9975a39be

Comment: Thanks. I can't seem to get it to work on `js`. I've added a gist

Comment: Hello @andi. Do you think you could help me? Many thanks :)

Comment: Question - why are you trying to decompress in browser through your own code, when browsers can handle gzipped data provided by a back-end server?

Comment: @snkashis. If that is the case, how do I simply read the file and make it available?

Comment: why do you have the `./` in front of the polylines.geojson path